# What does this quote from the book "1984" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm having some trouble understanding what this quote means:

> The object of power is power

The line is from 1984, by George Orwell.

The more I read it, the more it doesn't make sense. Could anyone please explain for me?

Comment: You may see the same idea expressed as "power is its own object."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about literary or cultural interpretation.

Comment: It is in the same vein as 'Chastity is its own reward'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially the quote means that those who have power, no matter how much, always want more, and that the principal aim of acquiring any power is to acquire more of it.

Answer (score -1):

It is a tautology or tautological statement. That is a statement that is logically true by definition, which is usually a triviality but often sounds philosophically profound. In this case it is true.